# setExclusiveTouch ignored when using UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, touch, uigesturerecognizer

I have two `UIViews` (custom scroll views) that respond to `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`. These two `UIViews` are **subviews** of the parent `UIView`. I want to **allow only one** of the subviews to respond to the recognizer.
In other words, only one should be allowed to be swiped at a time.

Setting `setExclusiveTouch = YES` on the subviews AND/OR the parent view doesn't have any effect.

How can I make sure that only 1 subview is being swiped at a time?

Here's a picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIScrollView's by default have `multipleTouchEnabled` set to YES - if you do not need multiple touch (zooming for example requires it), then set it to NO.